# Docker: Permission denied when running rocker/shiny-verse and rocker/shiny images

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I'm trying to run Shiny Server on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu.

Following [this page](https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/shiny), I run this command: `docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 rocker/shiny`.

I get the following warning and error:

`s6-supervise shiny-server: warning: unable to spawn ./run - waiting 10 seconds`

`s6-supervise (child): fatal: unable to exec run: Exec format error`

After that, those two outputs just repeat every 10 seconds. I can't even kill the process, so I have to close the terminal and start another one.

I'm new to Docker and have no real clue how to proceed from here. Any help would be appreciated.

**Updates**:

1. At least I've tracked down what [s6-supervise is](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-supervise.html): part of a set of utilities revolving around process supervision and management, logging, and system initialization.